# Syntax for retrieving data from GET, Host: function using APIs

Tags: javascript, api

I am using a price API. On the developer guide, the request example for Iphone 6 is shown as :

```
GET /api/v1/compare/search?product=iphone%207&api_key=YOUR_API_KEY HTTP/1.1
Host: https://price-api.datayuge.com
```

I have the API Key, but how should I use this in order to retrieve data (JSON format). Do I use `$.ajax()`, `$.getJSON()` or something else completely?

[This](https://price-api.datayuge.com/docs/#introduction) is the website that explains different formats, but I am not understanding how to put this all together:

Comment: Well as long as they actively support CORS, you can use a simple AJAX request, sure ...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Get-Host: syntax. what would the URL be in this case?

Comment: A GET has params in the URL: `https://price-api.datayuge.com/api/v1/compare/search?product=iphone%207&api_key=YOUR_API_KEY`.  As you can see, the browser does just fine getting the content.

Comment: _“I'm not familiar with the Get-Host: syntax. what would the URL be in this case?”_ - you simply combine the two, so that you have a full, absolute URL. `https://price-api.datayuge.com/api/v1/compare/search?product=iphone%207&api_key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Comment: I got it! Thank you!